# I am new to LaTeX

Tags: preamble

I am new to LaTex. I am writing a paper on a number theory topic. What I know so far is that I need to construct a preamble for my paper. I don't know what packages I need for my paper. What packages should I include? keep in mind this is an undergrad paper I am writing.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: First thing i would do is read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about what packages to include for now. Just start writing with the basic structure `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} ... \end{document}` and solve the problems (with the required packages) as they come along.

Comment: Welcome! Read an introduction, don't use a "template", _and_ do spent some time learning LaTeX. Knowledge on a good user level can save much time.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner.